# Does a switch duplicate multicast packets going to the same machine?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, multicast

Below my infrastructure:

```
[ Packet Sender Machine ] -------> [ S W I T CH ] ----------> [ Client Machine ]
```

Now let's say I have 10 different applications running independently in my `Client Machine` and each one of them has joined the same multicast group to receive the packet being sent to the multicast group.

**Question**: Does the `SWITCH`send 10 copies of the packet to the `Client Machine`? Or does it send only one and the network card in the machine distributes to all 10 applications? Does it matter? Should I code a `PROXY` on the `Client Machine` so that only one packet in transmitted to the `PROXY` and the 10 applications connect locally to the `PROXY`? Is there a standard network solution/configuration to this problem?

Comment: It doesn't duplicate multicast packets at all, let alone to the same machine. That's the whole point of multicast. Off topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A packet sent to a multicast group is like a broadcast, it goes everywhere. The difference is that hosts not subscribed to a multicast group simply ignore the multicast packet.

In fact multicast, by default, is restricted to a single network, so it never goes through a router. Routers route packets *between* networks, not from a network back to the same network. To route multicast to a different network, you must enable multicast routing, which is very different than unicast routing.

Comment: That went over my head. Does the client host gets 10 duplicate packets or just 1? Are you saying that the sender will send 10 packets? That does not sound right. I think you are wrong. You need a router/switch for multicast.

Comment: No. The sender sends a single multicast packet. If the medium is like a bus, then every host sees the single packet. If the medium is something like wired ethernet, then an ethernet switch will send the frame to all interfaces.

Comment: You misunderstood my question. I'm talking about 10 apps in the same host. They are all listening to multicast. Is the network card getting 10 identical UDP packets or just one?

Comment: Apparently, you don't understand the different network layers and how they work. The multicast frame is delivered at layer-2 (ethernet, etc.) to a NIC, but it will be only a single frame. The layer-2 protocol will strip off the frame, and deliver the packet to layer-3 (IP). The layer-3 protocol will strip off the pcaket and deliver the datagram to the transport protocol (UDP, etc.). Normally, multicast uses UDP, and only one application in a host can use a UDP port at any given time, so the mmulticast payload will be delivered to whichever application has registered with UDP for that UDP port.

Comment: Man! I'm talking about Multicast. You can have 100 apps joining the same multicast group and receiving the exact same multicast packet. My question  was very simple but you cannot answer it: In the situation I've just described is the machine receiving 100 identical multicast packets or just one? :/

Comment: I did answer that: "_The multicast frame is delivered at layer-2 (ethernet, etc.) to a NIC, but it will be only a single frame._" You just don't seem to understand. Yes, many hosts or applications in a host can subscribe to a multicast group, but you also need a transport protocol, and if you use UDP (the usual for multicast), only one application in a host can use a UDP port at any one time.

Comment: Man! That does not matter. They will still receive the same packets. I give up!

Comment: No. Applications do not receive packets. Packets are layer-3 datagrams. The transport protocols receives the payload of the packets, and it sends the payload of its datagrams to the application. The packets are at lower layers of the network stack, and the applications do not see the packets.

Comment: Great, but you still haven't anwered the original question :( Is the switch sending 10 times (one for each app) or just once (one for each machine). Is the NIC the one copying the single packet it receives ten times, one for each app. Or is the switch?

Comment: I answered the original question. You asked about a router sending the multicast. Multicast doesn't traverse a router unless you have configured multicast routing. Even then, it only sends packets one-for-one. You would not expect a router to replicate broadcast packets, and multicast is a form of broadcast.

Comment: @chicago-ny, since you have changed the question to a switch instead of a router, I still have answered the question. A switch will send a multicast frame to all the interfaces (although IGMP can modify that), but it only sends one frame for each received. A host interface will only receive one copy of the multicast frame, as I have told you twice already.